# Using TagFile in Liferay

Tags: javascript, jsp, liferay

I have wrote a sample Portlet and a number of Tag files which is called in the view.jsp file of portlet. Indeed, i have wrote a below code for calling Tag a Tag file in view.jsp

```
<%@taglib tagdir="/WEB-INF/tags/base" prefix="samfadBase"%>
```

Then, I have used below code in my view.jsp file.

```
<samfadBase:Initialize moduleName="ReportDefinition"></samfadBase:Initialize>
```

When I deploy my portlet, an exception is raised that is

```
ERROR [http-nio-8080-exec-5][PortletRequestDispatcherImpl:261] org.apache.jasper.JasperException: PWC6033: Error in Javac compilation for JSP__PWC6197: An error occurred at line: 11 in the jsp file: /html/reportViewer/reportDefinition/view.jsp_PWC6199: Generated servlet error:_package org.apache.jsp.tag.web.base does not exist__PWC6197: An error occurred at line: 11 in the jsp file: /html/reportViewer/reportDefinition/view.jsp_PWC6199: Generated servlet error:_package org.apache.jsp.tag.web.base does not exist__ [Sanitized]
org.apache.jasper.JasperException: PWC6033: Error in Javac compilation for JSP__PWC6197: An error occurred at line: 11 in the jsp file: /html/reportViewer/reportDefinition/view.jsp_PWC6199: Generated servlet error:_package org.apache.jsp.tag.web.base does not exist__PWC6197: An error occurred at line: 11 in the jsp file: /html/reportViewer/reportDefinition/view.jsp_PWC6199: Generated servlet error:_package org.apache.jsp.tag.web.base does not exist__ [Sanitized]
    at org.apache.jasper.compiler.DefaultErrorHandler.javacError(DefaultErrorHandler.java:129)
    at org.apache.jasper.compiler.ErrorDispatcher.javacError(ErrorDispatcher.java:299)
    at org.apache.jasper.compiler.Compiler.generateClass(Compiler.java:392)
    at org.apache.jasper.compiler.Compiler.compile(Compiler.java:453)
    at org.apache.jasper.JspCompilationContext.compile(JspCompilationContext.java:625)
    at org.apache.jasper.servlet.JspServletWrapper.service(JspServletWrapper.java:375)
    at org.apache.jasper.servlet.JspServlet.serviceJspFile(JspServlet.java:473)
    at org.apache.jasper.servlet.JspServlet.service(JspServlet.java:377)
    at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:729)
    at com.liferay.portal.osgi.web.servlet.jsp.compiler.JspServlet.service(JspServlet.java:399)
    at com.liferay.portal.osgi.web.servlet.jsp.compiler.JspServlet.service(JspServlet.java:410)
    at com.liferay.portal.osgi.web.servlet.context.helper.internal.JspServletWrapper.service(JspServletWrapper.java:70)
    at org.eclipse.equinox.http.servlet.internal.registration.EndpointRegistration.service(EndpointRegistration.java:153)
    at org.eclipse.equinox.http.servlet.internal.servlet.FilterChainImpl.doFilter(FilterChainImpl.java:50)
    at com.liferay.portal.kernel.servlet.filters.invoker.InvokerFilterChain.doFilter(InvokerFilterChain.java:119)
    at com.liferay.portal.kernel.servlet.filters.invoker.InvokerFilter.doFilter(InvokerFilter.java:115)
    at com.liferay.portal.osgi.web.wab.extender.internal.adapter.FilterExceptionAdapter.doFilter(FilterExceptionAdapter.java:46)
    at org.eclipse.equinox.http.servlet.internal.registration.FilterRegistration.doFilter(FilterRegistration.java:121)
    at org.eclipse.equinox.http.servlet.internal.servlet.FilterChainImpl.doFilter(FilterChainImpl.java:45)
    at org.eclipse.equinox.http.servlet.internal.servlet.ResponseStateHandler.processRequest(ResponseStateHandler.java:70)
    at org.eclipse.equinox.http.servlet.internal.context.DispatchTargets.doDispatch(DispatchTargets.java:117)
    at org.eclipse.equinox.http.servlet.internal.servlet.RequestDispatcherAdaptor.include(RequestDispatcherAdaptor.java:48)
    at com.liferay.portlet.PortletRequestDispatcherImpl.dispatch(PortletRequestDispatcherImpl.java:252)
    at com.liferay.portlet.PortletRequestDispatcherImpl.include(PortletRequestDispatcherImpl.java:102)
    at com.liferay.portal.kernel.portlet.bridges.mvc.MVCPortlet.include(MVCPortlet.java:556)
    at com.liferay.portal.kernel.portlet.bridges.mvc.MVCPortlet.include(MVCPortlet.java:572)
    at com.liferay.portal.kernel.portlet.bridges.mvc.MVCPortlet.doView(MVCPortlet.java:157)
    at org.samfad.base.controller.BaseController.doView(BaseController.java:107)
    at org.samfad.report.reportViewer.controller.ReportDefinitionController.doView(ReportDefinitionController.java:70)
    at com.liferay.portal.kernel.portlet.LiferayPortlet.doDispatch(LiferayPortlet.java:302)
    at com.liferay.portal.kernel.portlet.bridges.mvc.MVCPortlet.doDispatch(MVCPortlet.java:471)
    at javax.portlet.GenericPortlet.render(GenericPortlet.java:262)
    at com.liferay.portal.kernel.portlet.bridges.mvc.MVCPortlet.render(MVCPortlet.java:291)
    at com.liferay.portlet.FilterChainImpl.doFilter(FilterChainImpl.java:103)
    at com.liferay.portlet.ScriptDataPortletFilter.doFilter(ScriptDataPortletFilter.java:57)
    at com.liferay.portlet.FilterChainImpl.doFilter(FilterChainImpl.java:100)
    at com.liferay.portlet.ScriptDataPortletFilter.doFilter(ScriptDataPortletFilter.java:57)
    at com.liferay.portlet.FilterChainImpl.doFilter(FilterChainImpl.java:100)
    at com.liferay.portlet.ScriptDataPortletFilter.doFilter(ScriptDataPortletFilter.java:57)
    at com.liferay.portlet.FilterChainImpl.doFilter(FilterChainImpl.java:100)
    at com.liferay.portlet.ScriptDataPortletFilter.doFilter(ScriptDataPortletFilter.java:57)
    at com.liferay.portlet.FilterChainImpl.doFilter(FilterChainImpl.java:100)
    at com.liferay.portlet.ScriptDataPortletFilter.doFilter(ScriptDataPortletFilter.java:57)
    at com.liferay.portlet.FilterChainImpl.doFilter(FilterChainImpl.java:100)
    at com.liferay.portal.kernel.portlet.PortletFilterUtil.doFilter(PortletFilterUtil.java:64)
    at com.liferay.portal.kernel.servlet.PortletServlet.service(PortletServlet.java:105)
    at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:729)
    at com.liferay.portal.osgi.web.wab.extender.internal.adapter.ServletExceptionAdapter.service(ServletExceptionAdapter.java:68)
    at org.eclipse.equinox.http.servlet.internal.registration.EndpointRegistration.service(EndpointRegistration.java:153)
    at org.eclipse.equinox.http.servlet.internal.servlet.FilterChainImpl.doFilter(FilterChainImpl.java:50)
    at com.liferay.portal.kernel.servlet.filters.invoker.InvokerFilterChain.doFilter(InvokerFilterChain.java:119)
    at com.liferay.portal.kernel.servlet.filters.invoker.InvokerFilter.doFilter(InvokerFilter.java:115)
    at com.liferay.portal.osgi.web.wab.extender.internal.adapter.FilterExceptionAdapter.doFilter(FilterExceptionAdapter.java:46)
    at org.eclipse.equinox.http.servlet.internal.registration.FilterRegistration.doFilter(FilterRegistration.java:121)
    at org.eclipse.equinox.http.servlet.internal.servlet.FilterChainImpl.doFilter(FilterChainImpl.java:45)
    at org.eclipse.equinox.http.servlet.internal.servlet.ResponseStateHandler.processRequest(ResponseStateHandler.java:70)
    at org.eclipse.equinox.http.servlet.internal.context.DispatchTargets.doDispatch(DispatchTargets.java:117)
    at org.eclipse.equinox.http.servlet.internal.servlet.RequestDispatcherAdaptor.include(RequestDispatcherAdaptor.java:48)
    at com.liferay.portlet.InvokerPortletImpl.invoke(InvokerPortletImpl.java:529)
    at com.liferay.portlet.InvokerPortletImpl.invokeRender(InvokerPortletImpl.java:604)
    at com.liferay.portlet.InvokerPortletImpl.render(InvokerPortletImpl.java:391)
    at com.liferay.portal.monitoring.internal.portlet.MonitoringInvokerPortlet.render(MonitoringInvokerPortlet.java:261)
    at org.apache.jsp.html.portal.render_005fportlet_jsp._jspService(render_005fportlet_jsp.java:1549)
    at org.apache.jasper.runtime.HttpJspBase.service(HttpJspBase.java:70)
    at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:729)
```

Could you please helpme to solve this problem?

Comment: You forgot to deploy (or include in your deployment package) whatever jar file contains `org.apache.jsp.tag.web.base`. BTW, please learn how to use the formatting tools. I fixed your first post.

Comment: There is some compilation error in your tag file,considering it is imported to original jsp at line#11